# Preventing immutable object duplicates

Tags: c#, list, immutability

For a game I am creating alot of immutable objects that determine routines of NPCs.
One node object changes the value of x and z, one object the value of y, one object the angle and so on. I have a dozen different classes for them.
These objects are in combination a network of paths a NPC is walking.
These objects also get bundled into a bigger object which is the node. This node is manipulatin the NPC for a period of time until the next node is assigned.

I expect to have thousands of nodes in the end. But I am sure that the objects in these nodes are often duplicates of objects in some other nodes.

To keep the footprint of this system in my memory low I want that the object that changes the y value by 5 per frame is the very same object in every other node that has this object that changes the y value by 5. I want each node refer to the same object.

I try to archieve that by having the constructor of these objects set to private and use a method that returns either a new object if the parameters are unique or an already existing object that had the same parameters during it's creation.

I already succeed with that when I have a LinkedList for every class that I want to prevent to have identical objects of. Here is an example of how that looks like:

```
private class NodeEndTime : NodeEnd
{
   //attributes
   private readonly int dayTime;

   //constructor
   private NodeEndTime(int dayTime) { this.dayTime = dayTime; }

   //methods (only the one relevant for the question)
   public static NodeEndTime Constructor(int dayTime, LinkedList<NodeEndTime> list)
   {
      foreach (NodeEndTime node in list)
      {
         if (node.dayTime == dayTime) return node;
      }
      NodeEndTime fresh = new NodeEndTime(dayTime);
      list.AddLast(fresh);
      return fresh;
   }
}
```

What I dislike about this is that I need an unique LinkedList of every class. What I want instead is a list for all objects. But I don't know how to do that.
An idea would be to have a List of unique lists that creates the needed list as an attribute at runtime if it doesn't exist yet and does the work of accessing the correct list automatically. But I don't know how to do this either.

What would be a clean solution here? I suspect generics can help but I did not have enough experience with them to see a fitting approach with them. I also need to note that these lists will only exist during the loading process. The created objects are existing in a different structure that is usable by NPCs. So including them inside the class is not an option. Unless I can remove them somehow after loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need a class with a private constructor that creates some kind of key to uniquely identify the object. That can then be stored in a Dictionary and looked up each time you try to create a new instance. If an instance with the same key already exists, you return that, otherwise you create a new instance and add that to the dictionary. With something like this, you call `Get` and you'll either get an existing copy or a new instance.

```
public class NoDupeObject
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, NoDupeObject> _keyLookup = new Dictionary<string, NoDupeObject>();

    private NoDupeObject(string p1, int p2, DateTime p3) 
    {
        P1 = p1;
        P2 = p2;
        P3 = p3;
    }

    public string P1 { get; }
    public int P2 { get; }
    public DateTime P3 { get; }

    public static NoDupeObject Get(string p1, int p2, DateTime p3) 
    {
        var key = string.Join("-", p1, p2, p3);
        if (!_keyLookup.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
        {
            value = new NoDupeObject(p1, p2, p3);
            _keyLookup.Add(key, value);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Use as shown below. The method confirms that only two objects are created and o1 == o3

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        // Creates an object
        var o1 = NoDupeObject.Get("O1", 10, new DateTime(2020, 01, 01));
        // Creates another object
        var o2 = NoDupeObject.Get("O2", 10, new DateTime(2020, 01, 01));
        // Gets a copy of the first object
        var o3 = NoDupeObject.Get("O1", 10, new DateTime(2020, 01, 01));
        Debug.Assert(o1 != o2);
        Debug.Assert(o1 == o3);
    }
```

On a separate subject. Performance is often crucial in games, and iterating through a linked list at the point of object creation will be incredibly slow.

Comment: Working with keys surely makes things easier, but besides that I then have the dictionary sticking along during the whole runtime. The loading process only happens at the beginning, so to get rid of the dictionary I make it non-static and set it to null?

Comment: @Urben At the point you no longer need the dictionary you can set it to null. You'll still need it to be static, but setting to null will remove the reference and free it up for garbage collection.

Comment: Right, I did not mean non-static but non-readonly. Typo. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can make all the types that you want to cache implement `IEquatable`, you can do this relatively simply (as long as the types are NOT disposable; that would complicate things significantly).

Firstly, implement `IEquatable<T>` for all the types that you want to cache. This will allow you to store all the items in a single `HashSet`.

Then create a `HashSet<object>` to contain all the cached items:

```
static readonly HashSet<object> _lookup = new HashSet<object>();
```

Then when you want to get a new object, create the object (this is so you can use it as a key), then look it up in the `HashSet`. If it's found, return the found item; otherwise, add it to the `HashSet` and return the item you added.

Note that it's fairly fiddly to implement `IEquatable<T>` unless you're using something like Resharper, which will generate the code for you. (I've used Resharper for this purpose in the example below.)

This is best explained via an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var a1 = GetFirstType(42);
        var b1 = GetFirstType(43);
        var c1 = GetFirstType(42);

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(a1, b1))
            Console.WriteLine("a1 == b1");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("a1 != b1");

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(b1, c1))
            Console.WriteLine("b1 == c1");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("b1 != c1");

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(a1, c1))
            Console.WriteLine("a1 == c1");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("a1 != c1");

        Console.WriteLine();

        var a2 = GetSecondType("42");
        var b2 = GetSecondType("43");
        var c2 = GetSecondType("42");

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(a2, b2))
            Console.WriteLine("a2 == b2");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("a2 != b2");

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(b2, c2))
            Console.WriteLine("b2 == c2");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("b2 != c2");

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(a2, c2))
            Console.WriteLine("a2 == c2");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("a2 != c2");
    }

    public static FirstType GetFirstType(int value)
    {
        var item = new FirstType(value);

        if (_lookup.TryGetValue(item, out var found))
            return (FirstType) found;

        _lookup.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public static SecondType GetSecondType(string value)
    {
        var item = new SecondType(value);

        if (_lookup.TryGetValue(item, out var found))
            return (SecondType)found;

        _lookup.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    static HashSet<object> _lookup = new HashSet<object>();
}

public sealed class FirstType: IEquatable<FirstType>
{
    public FirstType(int value)
    {
        IntValue = value;
    }

    public int IntValue { get; }

    public bool Equals(FirstType? other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return IntValue == other.IntValue;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(this, obj) || obj is FirstType other && Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return IntValue;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(FirstType? left, FirstType? right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(FirstType? left, FirstType? right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}

sealed class SecondType: IEquatable<SecondType>
{
    public SecondType(string value)
    {
        StringValue = value;
    }

    public string StringValue { get; }

    public bool Equals(SecondType? other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return StringValue == other.StringValue;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(this, obj) || obj is SecondType other && Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return StringValue.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(SecondType? left, SecondType? right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(SecondType? left, SecondType? right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}
```

The important thing to note in this example is that I create two instances with the same value (42) and one with a different value (43) for FirstType and then for SecondType. I then compare the references of the objects returned from `GetFirstType()` and then `GetSecondType()` to prove that the same instance is returned if the underlying value is the same.

Once you have finished your initialisation, you can set the `HashSet` to `null` so that the GC can clean up any unused instances.

(Note: The code above assumes you are using `nullable` types - if you are not, remove all the `?`s from the type declarations.)